# scrollbar of text in python

Tags: python, tkinter, text, scrollbar

```
editor = Text(compiler, height=100, width=100)

editor.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(compiler)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT)
scrollbar.config(command=editor.yview)
```

[image]
[image: this picture is taken after clicking top scrollbar button once it is scrolling whole textView at once]
Above picture is taken after clicking top scrollbar button once it is scrolling whole textView at once

Now, the problem is I want to build a scrollbar like PyCharm. [image]

```
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
```

When I tried above code scrollbar was looking like this
[image]

scrollbar is unable to scroll properly(it is scrolling whole at once by clicking scroll button and when I am using `fill=Y` it is giving me huge scrollbar while I don't have anything in my textView). And, I want to scrollbar to works like PyCharm's scrollbar.

Comment: First `height=100` for a `Text` widget is a bit tall as it will be 100 lines tall not 100 pixels tall.  Second you forgot to call `editor.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)`.

Comment: Btw there is no way to create a scrollbar like the one you want (graphically) because tkinter only uses the windows default scrollbar. You can try to recreate it using a `tk.Canvas` but that is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) and [@TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard)

```
editor = Text(compiler, height=100, width=100)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(compiler)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=editor.yview)

editor.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
editor.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
```

It's working....now...